# Let $C\le A, D\le B$. Prove $C\times D=\{(c,d)\in A\times B:c\in C,d\in D\}$ is a subgroup of $A\times B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

> Let $C\le A, D\le B$. Prove $C\times D=\{(c,d)\in A\times B:c\in C,d\in D\}$ is a subgroup of $A\times B$

I know that in order to prove this, that the following needs to be proved:

- $C\times D$ needs to be closed under it's group operation, if $a,b\in C\times D$ then $ab\in C\times D$
- There needs to be an identity element, $1\in C\times D$ such that $1a = a$ where $a\in C\times D$
- There needs to be an inverse element: $a\in C\times D$  then $a^{-1}\in C\times D$ and $aa^{-1} = 1$

I'm pretty sure that I need to do all of this in order to complete the question, but I'm not sure where to start and how to prove this.

Comment: What have you tried? This is straightforward. Write the elements $a,b$ as $a=(c,d)$ and $b=(c',b')$ and start.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm a complete beginner at abstract algebra. I always struggle to write proofs and I don't know why. I just don't get how to prove things in this subject, I write out definitions etc. but it doesn't help

Comment: You just have to look up how $a\cdot b=(c,d)\cdot (c',d')$ was defined. You should really try yourself. This is really necessary for understanding. You say "you don't know why". But I know. It is always first about a definition. How is the product of pairs in a direct product defined? If you don't look it up yourself, then of course it cannot work.

Comment: Okay so a = (c,d) and b = (c',d') where a,b ∈ C x D. Then this means a.b = (c,d).(c',d'). This is where I get stuck, how does knowing that help me in answering the question? How does this prove that a.b ∈ C x D?

Comment: You have to find out first what $(c,d)\cdot (c',d')$ is by the definition how a direct product of groups is formed. You can only start when you have done this.

Comment: do you mean the definition : G × H = {(g, h) : g ∈ G, h ∈ H} where G and H are groups? So this would mean that a = (c,d) where c ∈ C and d ∈ D and b = (c',d') where c' ∈ C and d' ∈ D?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the direct product of two subgroups is a subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733974/prove-the-direct-product-of-two-subgroups-is-a-subgroup)

Comment: @Shaun I think it does, but it only shows the proof of the inverse and not the other two parts

Comment: I see. Sorry, @SuprDooprPoopr.

Comment: @Shaun No it's actually really helpful knowing how to do that part of the question, gives me an idea on how to do the other parts of it

Answer (score 1):

Use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.)

Since $A\le C$ and $B\le D$, we have $e_C\in A$ and $e_D\in B$; hence $(e_C,e_D)\in A\times B$. Thus $A\times B\neq \varnothing$.

By definition, $A\times B\subseteq C\times D$.

Let $x,y\in A\times B$. Then there exist $a,s\in A$ and $b,t\in B$ such that $x=(a,b), y=(s,t)$. Now

$$\begin{align}
xy^{-1}&=(a,b)(s,t)^{-1}\\
&=(a,b)(s^{-1},t^{-1})\\
&=(as^{-1}, bt^{-1}),
\end{align}$$

which is in $A\times B$,  since $as^{-1}\in A$ and $bt^{-1}\in B$ (as $A\le C$ and $B\le D$). So $xy^{-1}\in A\times B$.

Hence $A\times B\le C\times D$.